# Error message box overlapping in whole page

Tags: discussion, bug, user-interface, error-message, blog

Recently I'm reading the blog post *[A Theory of Moderation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/)*.

I noticed that when you click on the <kbd>POST COMMENT</kbd> button without filling in any details, one error message box is appearing with *Please fill out this field*.

When the error message box is appearing and at the same time we scroll the page the error message box still remains fixed at the same position and overlapping in the whole page not hiding while we scroll the page.

**Steps to reproduce**

> Click on the <kbd>POST COMMENT</kbd> button without filling in  any details.

Please check the below image for the same problem produced in Mozilla Firefox 58.0.

[image: ![Enter image description here]

**NOTE:** The problem is only produced in **Mozilla Firefox 58.0**

In Google Chrome 64.0.3282.119 it's working fine.

Is that a bug?

Comment: I do love the screenshot via camera, but you are missing the red freehand circles [.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/288751)

Comment: @TinyGiant i have updated screenshot in question thanks